# Create div element in JavaScript and add as parent of another div which was already exist in html file using pure vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Right now my .html file like this:

```
<body>
  <h2 id="h2">Child</h2>
</body>
```

Here I want to make a parent div Element of #h2. Here I cannot replace body element...
I want to create a parent div of h2 element like:-

**I want my html file like this using vanilla JavaScript.**

```
<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <h2 id="h2">Child</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should do the trick: create the parent element, append it in the body, and move (append) the h2 into the parent element.

```js
var parentEl = document.createElement("div")
parentEl.setAttribute("id", "parent")

document.body.appendChild(parentEl)
parentEl.append(document.getElementById("h2"))
```

```html
<body>
  <h2 id="h2">Child</h2>
</body>
```